# PL/SQL function input value seems not matching function input parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c, stored-functions

I've created this afternoon this PL/SQL function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CHECK_CIN_CLOSED_LINE
    (combination IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT '') 

   RETURN BOOLEAN 

IS 
    solution BOOLEAN := false;

    cursor c1 is
        SELECT (1)
        FROM RS2QTCIN cin, RS2QTGIN gin
        WHERE cin.group_id = gin.id
        AND cin.cin_value = combination
        and cin.date_end is not null;
    my_c1 c1%rowtype;
BEGIN
   open c1;

   FETCH c1 INTO my_c1;

   IF c1%NOTFOUND THEN
        IF c1%ROWCOUNT != 0 THEN
            solution := true;
        END IF;
   END IF;

   close c1;

RETURN solution;

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
   raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
END;
```

The problem comes when testing in with a simple call. 
For example :

```
select check_cin_closed_line('1PW2+UB07') from dual;
select CHECK_CIN_CLOSED_LINE('') from dual;
```

Both test calls return an error of invalid datatype (ORA-00902 - 00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype")
I dont't understand the reason of this error, the input parameter is varchar2 variable and the input value is a varchar value.

Comment: what's this `SELECT (1)` ..?

Comment: What if your return type is varchar2? I think boolean is not the correct data type for sql to handle

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I use this kind of query to check if exist an row that satisfy the conditions.

Comment: but it should produce error, maybe `SELECT COUNT(1)` might be preferred. Btw, a boolean value cannot be invoked within a SQL Statement, but might be assigned wthin a from PL/SQL Block as @Patrick Bacon stated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Boolean Data Type is Only Available in PLSQL, not in SQL**

Notice that if you comment most of the body of the function, you will receive the same error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_cin_closed_line (
    combination IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ''
) RETURN BOOLEAN IS
    solution BOOLEAN := false;

--    cursor c1 is
--        SELECT (1)
--        FROM RS2QTCIN cin, RS2QTGIN gin
--        WHERE cin.group_id = gin.id
--        AND cin.cin_value = combination
--        and cin.date_end is not null;
--    my_c1 c1%rowtype;
BEGIN
--   open c1;
--
--   FETCH c1 INTO my_c1;
--
--   IF c1%NOTFOUND THEN
--        IF c1%ROWCOUNT != 0 THEN
--            solution := true;
--        END IF;
--   END IF;
--
--   close c1;
    RETURN solution;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        raise_application_error(-20001, 'An error was encountered - '
                                        || sqlcode
                                        || ' -ERROR- '
                                        || sqlerrm);
END;
```

Check:

```
SELECT
    check_cin_closed_line('1PW2+UB07')
FROM
    dual;


SELECT
    check_cin_closed_line('')
FROM
    dual;
```

[image]

You can used the BOOLEAN data type in PLSQL, but not as the return type.

---

**What Can Be Done?**

Since you can use BOOLEAN data types in PLSQL and you want to see the results of this function invocation, perhaps use an anonymous PLSQL block and use a CASE statement to reveal the value of the BOOLEAN return value:

```
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line(
        CASE
            WHEN check_cin_closed_line('1PW2+UB07') THEN
                'true'
            ELSE 'false'
        END
    );
END;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I helps me a lot. I'm newbie with PL/SQL.